# Spark SQL performance: version 1.6 vs version 1.5

Tags: performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have tried to compare the performance of Spark SQL version 1.6 and version 1.5. In a simple case, Spark 1.6 is quite faster than Spark 1.5. However, in a more complex query - in my case an aggregation query with grouping sets, Spark SQL version 1.6 is very much slower than Spark SQL version 1.5. Does anybody notice the same issue? and even better have a solution for this kind of query?

Here is my code

```
case class Toto(
                 a: String = f"${(math.random*1e6).toLong}%06.0f",
                 b: String = f"${(math.random*1e6).toLong}%06.0f",
                 c: String = f"${(math.random*1e6).toLong}%06.0f",
                 n: Int = (math.random*1e3).toInt,
                 m: Double = (math.random*1e3))

val data = sc.parallelize(1 to 1e6.toInt).map(i => Toto())
val df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = sqlContext.createDataFrame( data )

df.registerTempTable( "toto" )
val sqlSelect = "SELECT a, b, COUNT(1) AS k1, COUNT(DISTINCT n) AS k2, SUM(m) AS k3"
val sqlGroupBy = "FROM toto GROUP BY a, b GROUPING SETS ((a,b),(a),(b))"
val sqlText = s"$sqlSelect $sqlGroupBy"

val rs1 = sqlContext.sql( sqlText )
rs1.saveAsParquetFile( "rs1" )
```

Here are 2 screenshots [Spark 1.5.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VujQY.png) and [Spark 1.6.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hlg95.png) with --driver-memory=1G. The DAG on Spark 1.6.0 can be viewed at [DAG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3HrG.png).

Comment: Seems that it is shuffling more in 1.6, can you post the two DAGs ?

Comment: Thanks @SebastianPiu. You can see the 2 screenshots with empty DAGs at [spark 1.5.2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dLXiK.png) and [spark 1.6.0](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4oomU.png). In other cases, Spark still displays DAGs correctly.

Comment: yeah, sadly this is a bug caused when chrome got updated so impossible to troubleshoot the DAGs :(

Comment: @SebastianPiu Oh indeed. Firefox can show the [DAG](http://i.stack.imgur.com/u3HrG.png) properly.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Herman van Hövell for his reply on spark dev community. In order to share with other members, I share his response here.

> 1.6 plans single distinct aggregates like multiple distinct aggregates; this inherently causes some overhead but is more stable in case of high cardinalities. You can revert to the old behavior by setting the spark.sql.specializeSingleDistinctAggPlanning option to false. See also: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/SQLConf.scala#L452-L462

Actually in order to revert the setting value should be "true".